# Resnet50+LSTM to classify the video frames

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to implement a Resnet50+LSTM to classify the video frames into different 7 phases (classes). In my train files, I have 5 folders, each one includes a video that is captured as some frames which show one phase of a specific action(the action is identical for all the videos). Now I want to use Resnet50+LSTM to classify the action phase recognition. Also, I want to use 4 nearby frames. I implement the following codes with Keras, but I have some questions.

```
inputs = Input((4, 224, 224, 3))
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False,input_shape =(224,224,3), weights='imagenet')
for layer in resnet.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet.output)
cnn = tf.keras.Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=output)
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inputs)


lstm = LSTM(2048)(encoded_frames)
out_leaky = LeakyReLU()(lstm)
out_drop = Dropout(0.4)(out_leaky)
out_dense = Dense(2048,input_dim=inputs,activation='relu')(out_drop)
out_1 = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(out_dense)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=out_1)
```

1. I have used 'GlobalAveragePooling2D' to have 4 nearby frames. But I was reading that I should load 4 nearby frames in each iteration of the dataloader. It means that in each iteration, the dataloader should load (B, N, 3, H, W) (batch_size, # of nearby frames, channels, H, W). What should I do?
2. I want to use my model in a PyTorch environment. Can you help me to convert it?
3. Also, about the input of resnet50 and LSTM, I use these numbers based on the error that I received. Can you explain them to me?
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do?

Why not using a 3D conv network? It gives the best results according to papers with code (https://paperswithcode.com/sota/action-classification-on-kinetics-400). To this type of networks you feed (B, N, 3, H, W). Then the model classifies the set of frames inputed to the model

> Can you help me to convert it?

If your destination framework is PyTorch why not using the already existing models in TorchVision for this task (3D conv model used below)?

```py
from torchvision.io.video import read_video
from torchvision.models.video import r3d_18, R3D_18_Weights

vid, _, _ = read_video("/path/to/your/test/video.avi", output_format="TCHW")
vid = vid[:32]  # optionally shorten duration

# Step 1: Initialize model with the best available weights
weights = R3D_18_Weights.DEFAULT
model = r3d_18(weights=weights)
model.eval()

# Step 2: Initialize the inference transforms
preprocess = weights.transforms()

# Step 3: Apply inference preprocessing transforms
batch = preprocess(vid).unsqueeze(0)

# Step 4: Use the model and print the predicted category
prediction = model(batch).squeeze(0).softmax(0)
label = prediction.argmax().item()
score = prediction[label].item()
category_name = weights.meta["categories"][label]
print(f"{category_name}: {100 * score}%")
```